# Mercurial external precommit hook: get changed files list

Tags: mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

I could get it either with

```
hg status --change $HG_NODE
```

or with

```
hg log -r $HG_NODE --style mycustomstyle
```

But I can't get `HG_NODE` in precommit hook. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
hg status --change $HG_NODE
```

is what you want, I guess you could just use:

```
hg status
```

Answer (score 0):

$HG_NODE is not available in precommit since the changeset was not created yet

You may use the pretxncommit instead (Run after a new changeset has been created in the local repository, but before the transaction completes that will make it permanent)

Note that since the changeset is already 'done', modifications made to sources by the hooks will not be applied in the current changeset.

I'm currently trying to update a source file with the current changeset while committing, but I didn't found a solution yet